# Resizing image in bootstrap via html file

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap-3, resize

I'm new to all of this. I'm learning bootstrap 3 and during the process I've encountered a problem.

I'm using the `<div class="row">` and `<div class="col-md-4>` to make a 3 symmetrical column with 3 images + 1 little description for each of them.

Here's my issue: I don't know how to resize the images in my html file... I just want to make them smaller so they can all fit in my column.

Can't post my code... its too long I guess

Comment: try `class="img-responsive"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="layouts/layouts.PNG" />
            <p>Some description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="layouts/layouts.PNG" />
            <p>Some description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="layouts/layouts.PNG" />
            <p>Some description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The Comment of "Dan" is executed here.